# Cannot get mouse coordinates, but all the code is from on and it has worked for others

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I found this code on here but when I tried implementing it into my code but it won't work. I am not a professional coder and am therefore asking you guys for assistance. 
Is it a reference problem? Or is there some other way of getting the cursor to click?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MouseWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

         }
    }
    public class form1 : Grid 
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(long dwflags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP= 0x10;
        public static Point Position { get; set; }
        public form1 ()
        {

        }
        public void DoMouseClick()
        {
//This is where the error is, System.Windows.Input.Cursor' does not contain a definition for 'Position' //
            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Does it gives you 0,0? Does it produces an error?

Comment: "it won't work" - this is not precise enough. Please describe *exactly* what is happening. Nothing at all, compared to before you inserted that code? An error message (which one?)? An exception (which one?)? Anything else that was not expected (what?)?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' does not contain a definition for 'Position' and no extension method 'Position' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem when developing a winforms game editor. I fixed it by creating an onMouseMove Event on the form you want to get the mouse coordinates from. If you don't know how to make an event, go to the form editor, click on the form, and click on the thunderbolt in the properties box. Go ahead and make the name of it onMouse and then here's some code to demonstrate how to get the right coordinates.

```
 private void onMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "X:" + e.X + "Y:" + e.Y;
    }
```

Comment: For some reason, the Cursor property gives the coordinates of the mouse in relation to the actual size of the screen, rather than the coordinates within your application.

Comment: That is what I wanted ^^